# Компиляция sdk25 на sdk19

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Разработано приложение для sdk 25 (7.1 платформа).

(Функционал элементарен:
- три страницы с кнопками и текстами
- на одной из страниц вызывается камера и фотка сделанная на камеру попадает назад в превьюшку)

Когда это приложение хочу скомпилировать на sdk 19 (4.4.2 платформа) то много объектов подсвечивается красным цветом, как будто на 19сдк нет таких объектов.

Как заставить мой код компилироваться и на 4.4.2?

(на разработки использую андр студио)

Comment: какие именно места подсвечивает? примеры, код.

Comment: сейчас, удаляю 7.1 сдк, оставлю только 4.4 и скажу )

Comment: ну короче, пока установлен 7.1 и пытаюсь запустить на 4.4 то пишет вот такое http://prntscr.com/feni3w
а если удалю 7.1 то сразу подсвечиваются много элементов кода, ща покажу какие

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fenp6i вот 4.4 оставил и понеслась

Comment: Пересоберите проект

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: Build -> Clean Project

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fenxac изменил build.gradle/, теперь тонна ошибок посыпалась

Comment: а для чего очищать проект?

Comment: спасибо, нужно было minSDKversion = 19 изменить и синхронизировать и все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле build.gradle уровня модуля укажите `minSDKversion = 19`. Сейчас у вас стоит ограничение на запуск на устройствах с API>=25 (`minSDKversion = 25`), а вы пытаетесь запустить свой проект на устройстве с API = 19